# angular ng-repeat not updating, when angular method is called with jquery inside directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

(First time Angular user)

So I'm trying to call the angular method I created `addField` function (which works if I call it with ng-click) when another element is dropped using jqueryUI draggable and droppable.

The drag and drop work fine, and it's even updating my model properly, because when I run `$scope.fields` in the console when breaking inside the `addField` function it finds my objects right.

The issue is that although the objects are there, it's not displaying them in the `ng-repeat` html like it did with `ng-click`.

**ANGULAR**

```
angular.module('formApp', [])
    .controller('formController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.fields = [
            //{label:'The Field Title, with Angular', desc:'Lorem Ipsum Dolor', req:false},
            //{label:'The Other Field Title, with Angular', desc:'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Dos', req:false}
            ];
        $scope.addField = function() {
            $scope.fields.push({label:'Added Form Title', desc:'Added Form Desc', req:true});
            //$scope.fieldLabel = '';
            console.log("addField");
        };
    }])
    .directive('drag', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $( elem ).draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
    })
    .directive('drop', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $( elem ).droppable({
                hoverClass: "holder-state-highlight",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    //handleDropEvent(event, ui);
                    //sortOrder();
                    angular.element('#theForm').scope().addField();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the `angular.element(...)` call in a `$scope.$apply()`?  You can read more about `$apply` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: try setting a plain js variable like: `var fieldsArray = $scope.fields = [what you have here]` and then `push` into `fieldsArray` instead of `$scope.fields`. No idea why this works, but they use this pattern in the [todos mvc](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/angularjs/js/controllers/todoCtrl.js#L12) and it works.

Comment: @BrianS that works! Use as the answer and I'll check it off :)

Comment: Glad it worked, @Reuben.  Answer is below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the jQuery drop callback occurs outside the Angular framework, so Angular has no knowledge of it happening.  In this case, you need to notify Angular by wrapping it in an `$apply`, as follows:

```
.directive('drop', ['$scope', function($scope) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $( elem ).droppable({
            hoverClass: "holder-state-highlight",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                  //handleDropEvent(event, ui);
                  //sortOrder();
                  $scope.$apply(angular.element('#theForm').scope().addField());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

You can read more about Angular's `$apply` function [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply).